# Detect file type in android

Tags: android

I am working on an android app. The app has a picture gallery. The pictures are stored on a remote server.

I am showing the pictures as follows:

```
String imgUrl = "http://.path to the file.../"+valueList.get(position).archivo_foto;

Picasso.with(context)
    .load(imgUrl)
    .into(viewItem.Imagen);
```

The app lets the user to download the picture to his device. That is working fine.

Now I need to add video files as well. The app is working fine, also for the video files, that means, that the user can download the video files and the image files, but only the image files are shown in the imageView, as usual.

My question is, what should I do? Could I detect the file type? Image or video? And could I change the app behaviour? I mean, to include a media player in case of video file and use the imageView for images?

Comment: You could detect the file type, the simplest way is to check for the extension (which is lame, but Windows for example does it that way), but I think it's unnecessary work. Just put video and photos on different URLs.

Comment: @m0skit0 thank you. And could I then merge imageview and mediaplayer in the same gallery?

Comment: Do you mean `VideoView`? Yes, why not, but you'll have to create the views dynamically.

Comment: @m0skit0, thank you. I will try it